# Laravel Livewire: Cómo se forza a que un componente se repinte

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Estoy haciendo un componente de "favorito". El componente pinta una estrella que adquiere tres clases de acuerdo a su estado. Para seleccionar la clase que se debe aplicar, utilizo una "computed property":

```
public function getEsFavoritaProperty() {
    return $this->idea->users()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->count() > 0;
}

public function getFavoritaProperty() {
    if (Auth::guest()) return 'voto-idea-inactivo';

    if ($this->EsFavorita) {
      return 'voto-idea-seleccionado';
    }

    return 'voto-idea-activo';
}
```

Si no hay usuario firmado (guest) regresa la clase `voto-idea-inactivo`, Si el usuario está firmado, regresa la clase correspondiente de acuerdo a si existe la relación de favoritos en la base de datos.

Las funciones operan como se espera. Si cambio los datos en la tabla pivote, y refresco la página web, se le aplican las clases precisas a la estrella.

En la estrella tengo:

```
<a wire:click.prevent="toggleFavorita">
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x {{ $this->favorita }}"></i>
</a>
```

Para que cambie (attach/detach) la relación. La función es muy simple:

```
public function toggleFavorita() {
    if ($this->EsFavorita) {
        $this->idea->users()->detach(Auth::user()->id);
    } else {
        $this->idea->users()->attach(Auth::user()->id);
    }
}
```

Esto también funciona, cuando se hace click y se ejecuta la función, los cambios se ven reflejados en la base de datos.

El problema es que el DOM no se repinta y se queda indicando el estado anterior, por lo que la pregunta es: ¿cómo se forza a que se repinte el componente (o una parte de él)?

Comment: Revisa si el contenido del hilo te ayuda https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/1023 sobre todo donde comenta kaleb

Comment: No, en realidad no, porque necesito que se ejecuten dos acciones, una llamar a mi función y la otra hacer el `$refresh`. Si pongo el `$refresh` en otro botón, pues si, funciona, pero dejo de llamar a la función, y si uso `toggleFavorita; $refresh` aparece un error de sintaxis

Comment: No es necesario poner `$this->favorita` en tu vista, simplemente poniendo `$favorita` es suficiente

Comment: `favorita` es un *computed property*, de acuerdo a la documentación es necesario. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#computed-properties  Pero lo pruebo, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final, después de muchos `Log::info()`'s encontré el problema y no tiene que ver con refrescar el componente.

Lo que estaba haciendo es que dentro de una función estaba buscando acceder a una **computed propery**. Al parecer, en el ciclo de vida, estas son las que se actualizan hasta el final. Lo que hice fue convertir ese **atributo** en una función normal, y llamarla como tal. Los cambios que hice en la aplicación quedan como:

```
public function EsFavorita() {
    return $this->idea->users()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->count() > 0;
}

public function getFavoritaProperty() {
    if (Auth::guest()) return 'voto-idea-inactivo';

    if ($this->EsFavorita()) {
      return 'voto-idea-seleccionado';
    }

    return 'voto-idea-activo';
}
```

Y todo funciona como debería... a veces la cosa es más simple